# Fixing a winter tire with poking studs using tube patches. Will it work?

Tags: tire, repair, winter, studded, fix

My rear tire, a Schwalbe Marathon winter K-guard 120 studs, had some studs poking through the inner casing of the tire after approximately 1300km/1 winter season. It happened on two separate occasions giving me a flat tire which I only realized the next morning. I'm guessing it is due to braking/cornering too hard, impact from running over a curb edge or perhaps just poor design. Unfortunately I did my fix before taking photos, but it looked pretty much like this (pic from a YT vid review of a similar Scwhalbe tire).

I have put some tube-patches on top of the holes, and removed the spikes from these places. I might also put some duct tape on top just to reinforce things further.

[image]

[image]

I realize the traction is reduced since I removed the spikes at the damaged areas, and the strength of the tire is somewhat compromised since a thread or two have been severed, but still, I'm taking my chances. My question is, have anyone tried this or a similar fix with or without success?

Comment: Knowing the pressure you run could be helpful.

Comment: Very closely related: [Mystery puncture -- caused by inner end of ice spike?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/44644/7309) (my question). I'm even tempted to call it a duplicate. My solution was to run tyre liners, leaving the spikes in

Comment: @NathanKnutson The tire asks for 30-70 PSI, I usually go for something in the middle. I probably ran 50, and I am planning to keep doing that.

Comment: @ChrisH Related yes, but I'm not asking for the cause of punctures in tube/tire (which you did), that is IMO without doubt caused by the studs. I'm asking if anyone have tried a fix like mine or similar. With or without success.

Comment: I'd be tempted to try a tire liner so the next time one pops through the tire casing it won't be attacking the tube directly.

Comment: @WornChain I didn't change the question title, but after the discussion in the comments, answered my own question with an answer that includes an answer to yours

Comment: @AndrewHenle it works

Comment: @ChrisH I can't see anyone in that post mentioned using tube patches to patch the tire. Liners are mentioned as a possible solution, as is using a piece of an old tube. So you suggest another solution, which is fine. I'm still curious if anyone have tried this.

Comment: I wouldn’t have removed the studs. The Marathon Winter has relatively few to begin with, so removing them kind of defeats the purpose of running a studded tyre in the first place.

Comment: @WornChain - from my answer *"To be on the safe side I'll cover that point with a **patch** or liner next winter."* But the liner that I settled on is similar only much much better

Comment: Well, that is written as something you "will do" next winter. NOT something you have tried. In the next paragraph you write as if months have gone by and you used a liner. Even though you don't clarify this. It's hard to tell the timeline of your experience and what you actually did when it is written in that way.

Comment: @WornChain Schwalbe recommend the high end of the range for roads with a risk of ice, and the low end for snow.  That's why it's so wide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've ridden the "fixed" tire at 4 bar for more than 400 kms in all kinds of horrible conditions with no issues so far. I put a single layer of duct tape on top of the patches just to smooth tings out even more. I inspected the inside of the tire yesterday, and everything looked as it should.

Just in case anyone wants to get a few more kms out of their tires (At their own risk of course).

Edit: After 400 additional kilometres (2100km totally for the tire), the studs poked through new parts of the tire/inner tube, and the tube is full of non fatal markings in many other places (the original fix is still good). Put in an old inner tube as a layer of protection which has worked fine the last 100 kms of the winter season.

Answer (score 1):

The backs of studs are wide, blunt and rounded off slightly; that you pushed them through the casing is very odd. The casing may be defective, or you may run extremely high pressures - you mention 50psi, but not the tire size or your system weight.
[image: Schwalbe studs]

I find studs protruding through the casing to be an extremely serious casing failure, on par with a wide sidewall gash that goes all the way through.  I would write the tire off.

Comment: Tire size: 622 x 42mm. Approximately a 80kg rider on a 13 kg bike. Everything pretty standard. They are not pushed through, the edge of the bottom of the stud cuts through the casing. Probably due to hard breaking that the tires are not designed to handle in the long run.

Comment: If you see the question I linked in the comments, this isn't actually uncommon, and is far more localised than a sidewall gash

Comment: @WornChain I’ve ridden studded tires pretty aggressively. If you are concerned your riding style caused it, you could switch to Continental Spike 240s, they come in 622 by 422 and are much faster and better suited to what you might call aggressive or intense riding.  I have a bias against Schwalbe tires, but you could also try the higher end Marathon Plus Winter, they should have a more reinforced casing.

Comment: @ChrisH the tire in the linked question is also a basic Schwalbe Winter. Pwrhaps the cheaper casing is prone to this. Continental studded tires are better anyway

Comment: @oscu0 Thanks for the tip. I'll consider them if they can compete price-wise when I'm forced to get new tires. I'll try my fix and see how it goes first. I have in fact tried the Plus Winter as well, they don't have the same issue yet, but I placed the Plus tire on the front wheel so it's not really a fair comparison.

Comment: @oscu0 Conti winter tyres are hard to get round here, and I've always found conti hard to fit - but maybe that's just because I didn't get on with my gators but didn't want to waste them

Comment: They are harder to fit, but you know, that’s not the main function of tires 8) They’re a lot faster in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I made my own MTB ice tires by screwing sheet metal screws thru the inside of the tire with the pointy end facing out. The heads were obviously going to damage the tubes. I installed SlimeLiners between the tube and the inside of the tire. I rode them for 3 seasons with no punctures.